# Allow Concurrent Requests Per Session with Session State Provider inheriting from SessionStateStoreProviderBase

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm using a third party CMS which is using a custom SessionStateProvider which is inheriting from `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateStoreProviderBase`. `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule` is used as SessionStateModule.

I need to allow concurrent request per session with a writable session. This can be done using the `aspnet:AllowConcurrentRequestsPerSession` setting when using the AsyncSessionStateModule from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetSessionState).  This would meet my requirement but this requires the provider to inherit from `Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateStoreProviderAsyncBase` and the provider from the third party CMS does not.

I understand this can be achieved by implementing `ISessionStateModule` but this seems high risk and easy to get wrong. Is there already a `SessionStateModule` somewhere which meet my requirements (it seems like I cannot be the first to run into this issue)?

- Allows concurrent requests per session
- Writable session (i.e. no `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` to achieve concurrent request)
- Supports a provider inheriting from `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateStoreProviderBase`

Or am I missing something here and can this be achieved in an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [`Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule) in a couple of different scenarios.

1. `Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStoreAsync` - This provider is included in the NuGet package and is a lot simpler to use as it does not require an external dependency. However, you need to ensure the user is hitting the same web-server. If you have a multiple server deployment, this requires "sticky sessions" on the load balancer.
2. `Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider` - This provider requires 2 additional NuGet packages ([`Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider) and [`StackExchange.Redis`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis)) and an instance of Redis. While Redis is indeed very powerful, it may take some tweaking to get running smoothly. Do an internet search for "StackExchange Redis Timeout" and you will see a common problem that people face with this driver. I would only recommend this configuration in a multiple server configuration where you do not have "sticky sessions" on your load balancers.

Example web.config settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:AllowConcurrentRequestsPerSession" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <!-- Option 1: InProcSessionStateStoreAsync -->
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="InProcSessionStateStoreAsync" cookieless="UseCookies">
    <providers>
      <add name="InProcSessionStateStoreAsync" type="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStoreAsync" />
    </providers>
  </sessionState>

  <!-- Option 2: RedisSessionStateProvider -->
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateProvider" cookieless="UseCookies">
    <providers>
      <add name="RedisSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" connectionString="..." />
    </providers>
  </sessionState>

</configuration>
```

As a side note, it looks like the `AspNetSessionState` project may already come with [`CosmosDB`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetSessionState/blob/main/docs/CosmosDBSessionStateProviderAsync.md) and [`Sql`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetSessionState/blob/main/docs/SqlSessionStateProviderAsync.md) providers. YMMV - But you could try one of those if you wanted an external state server other than Redis. I ended up going with Redis mainly because it was used elsewhere in my app.